# Termwise max (resp. min) of two convergent (resp. divergent) series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

If $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty b_n$ converge, does $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \max\{a_n, b_n\}$ also converge?

Similarly, if $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty b_n$ diverge, does $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \min\{a_n, b_n\}$ also diverge?

My intuition tells me the answer to both of these questions is yes, but I don't know how to verify it.

Edit: $a_n \ge 0, b_n \ge 0\ \forall n$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint. As regards the max case, note that 
$$0\leq\max\{a_n, b_n\}\leq a_n+b_n$$ 
For the min case take 
$$a_n=1+(-1)^n+e^{-n}>0\quad\mbox{and}\quad b_n=1+(-1)^{n+1}+e^{-n}>0
\implies  \min\{a_n, b_n\}=e^{-n}.$$
What may we conclude?

P.S. As regards the max case, without the assumption of non negativity, we have a counterexample:
 $$a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}\quad\mbox{and}\quad b_n=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}\implies \max\{a_n, b_n\}=\frac{1}{n+1}.$$

Comment: I initially forgot to say it in my question, but the terms are nonnegative.

Comment: @OpticAl I edited my answer.

Comment: For the max: This is so simple, why haven't I thought of that? For the min, this is also so simple, but I thought of something even simpler: $a_n$ is 1 if $n$ is odd and 0 if $n$ is even, $b_n = 1 - a_n$.

Comment: @OpticAl Yes, well done! You are correct!

Answer (score 0):

Even if $a_n,b_n\searrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, it is possible for
$$\sum_n\min(a_n,b_n)<\infty$$
when $\sum_na_n=\sum_nb_n=\infty$.

Here is a way to construct an example:

- Consider positive sequences  $u_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$ and $v_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ so that $\sum_nu_n<\infty$ and $\sum_nv_n=\infty$.
  By alternating sequences $u_n$ and $v_n$ we define sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ by letting
  \begin{align}
  a_{2n-1}&=v_n,\qquad a_{2n}=u_n\\
  b_{2n-1}&=u_n,\qquad b_{2n}=v_n
  \end{align}
  The series $\sum_na_n$ and $\sum_nb_n$ diverge. However, since
  $$\min(a_{2n},b_{2n})=\min\Big(\frac{1}{n^2},\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\Big)=\frac{1}{n^2}$$
  and
  $$\min(a_{2n-1},b_{2n-1})=\min\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},\frac{1}{n^2}\Big)=\frac{1}{n^2}$$
  we have that
  $$\sum_n\min(a_n,b_n)=2\sum_n\frac{1}{n^2}<\infty$$

The sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ are not monotone. We can use them to build a monotone example as follows:

- Define $n_1=1$, and for $k>1$
  $$ n_k=\min\left\{n\in\mathbb{N}: n>\max\Big(\frac{n_{k-1}a_k}{a_{k-1}},\frac{n_{k-1}b_k}{b_{k-1}}\Big)\right\}$$
  Then $\frac{a_k}{n_k}<\frac{a_{k-1}}{n_{k-1}}$ and $\frac{b_k}{n_k}<\frac{b_{k-1}}{n_{k-1}}$. Let $N_0=0$, $N_k=\sum^k_{j=1}n_j$ for $k\geq 1$. Define sequences $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as
  \begin{align}
  \alpha_m&=\frac{a_k}{n_k}\qquad\text{if}\quad N_{k-1}+1\leq m\leq N_k\\
  \beta_m&=\frac{b_k}{n_k}\qquad\text{if} \quad N_{k-1}+1\leq m\leq N_k
  \end{align}
  $\alpha_m,\beta_m\searrow0$ as $m\rightarrow\infty$ and
  \begin{align}
  \sum_m\alpha_m&=\sum^\infty_{k=1}\sum^{N_k}_{j=N_{k-1}+1}\frac{a_k}{n_k}=\sum_ka_k=\infty\\
  \sum_m\beta_m&=\sum^\infty_{k=1}\sum^{N_k}_{j=N_{k-1}+1}\frac{b_k}{n_k}=\sum_kb_k=\infty
  \end{align}
  and
  $$\sum_m\min(\alpha_m,\beta_m)=\sum_k\min(a_k,b_k)<\infty$$